# Meteor: Rerun code when template variable changes

Tags: javascript, meteor

I created a template, an audioplayer-element. The id of the audio-file is passed to the element via a template-variable. Something like this:

```
{{>audioPlayer audio=audio}}
```

The containing template is used for subsequent pages so the audioPlayer doesn't get rerendered, only the content of the pages change (like having page/1, page/2, page/3 with on every page this element on the same place).
What I want to do now is load the correct file, matching the id of the variable passed. I do this with howler, and I need a subscription to get the url of the file related to the id.

```
Template.audioPlayer.created = function () {

    var audioId = this.data.audio;
    var subscription = this.subscribe('audio', audioId); //this is where the variable is

    if (subscription.ready()) {
        var audioUrl = Audio.findOne(audioId).url;
        var audio = new Howl({
            urls: [audioUrl]
        })
    }
}
```

Because this is the created-function this is only run once, but I want to have it run every time I go to a new page, to make sure I have the correct audio file matching to the right page.

I've tried wrapping this piece in a Tracker.autorun but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. It doesn't react on a change of the this.data.audio-variable. The variable itself does change, at least it does when I put this variable in a helper and display it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `audioId` isn't reactive. You'll need to change that to a Session var, or (even better) a query parameter in the url. I'll assume you know how to do this.

OK, now that we have a reactive variable, we need to rerun a block of code every time that variable changes. Let's use an autorun.

As you have it, that block of code is a subscription, but it only returns 1 result & chances are that url isn't going to change while someone is listening to their tunes. That's a sad, sorry subscription. What would be better is if you had a method that grabbed only the url from the server.

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var audioId = Session.get('audioId');
  Meteor.call('getAudioUrl', function(err,res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var audio = new Howl({
      urls: [res]
    })
  })
});

//in the server folder
Meteor.methods({
  'getAudioUrl': function(audioId) {
    return Audio.findOne(audioId).url;
  }
});
```

Boom. No useless subs & all the reactivity you can shake a stick at.

Comment: I highly recommend Not using session variables. They are basically pollution.

You should read this: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

Comment: Thanks for your solution Matt! I haven't tried it yet, it probably works but using this solution it wouldn't be possible to have multiple audioPlayer's one page? Because it uses one specific Session-variable or query paramater to get the right file. For me it doesn't really make sense to do it like this, because from the database it is already known what file it should play on what page, you wouldn't want a separate variable saying what file to play, right?

Comment: @SirCharlesWatson I read that blog before (see current solution) but I guess the audioId isn't reactive apparently so the subscription doesn't get updated. How would you make that reactive?
Why isn't it reactive actually? Is it because it's in de created-function? Because when using this.audio in a helper it gets updated on a new page for example.

Comment: I don't understand, you need multiple audio players on a page, but each page only plays 1 song?